# r check_model() for model summaries as list objects and 6 plots in 1 row

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, diagnostics

I'm using the `check_model` function within the **performance** library in r to check the assumptions of a simple linear regression model using `lm`.

I am fitting 3 models on different subsets of the data.

```
data("mtcars")
head("mtcars")

table(mtcars$cyl, useNA = "ifany")

foo <- mtcars %>%
          group_by(cyl) %>%
             nest() %>%
               mutate(model= map(data, lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = .))

foo %>%
    {map(.$model, summary)}
```

I want `check_model` to plot all the 6 diagnostic plots per model in one row. Which means 3 rows, 6 plots in each row, using the model summaries which is stored as a list object.

```
check_model(foo$model..cylinder 4)...all 6 plots in 1 row
check_model(foo$model..cylinder 6)...all 6 plots in 1 row
check_model(foo$model..cylinder 8)...all 6 plots in 1 row
```

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach:

1. create list of models, one model per level of `cyl` (here: by `split`ing and `Map`ping):

```
the_models <- 
  split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) |>
  Map(f = \(d) lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = d))
```

2. map above list into list of plots. The plots produced by `plot`ting the result of `check_model` have, besides being ggplot-objects, class `patchwork`, meaning that you can specify the `plot_layout` (a function provided by package {[patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/index.html)}):

```
the_plots <- 
  the_models |>
  Map(f = \(m) check_model(m) |>
               plot() +
               ## lay out diagnostic plots
               ## into 6 columns, 1 row per model:
               plot_layout(6, 1)
      )
```

3. combine (`Reduce`) the list of plots into one stack. With {patchwork}, you [stack plots with `/`](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html):

```
the_plots |> Reduce(f = `/`)
```

[image: use {patchwork} to row-bind plots]

**edit**
The output for a larger number of models (= rows) may exceed the device dimensions (`Error: The viewport may be too small to show this patchwork. Please make it larger.`) If you don't need live preview, you can assign the combined plots to an object and save it like so:

```
all_plots <- the_plots |> Reduce(f = `/`)
ggsave(all_plots, filename = 'all_plots.pdf', height = 20, width = 15)
```

(`ggsave` can save in various raster and vector formats, guessing from the filename's extension.)

Comment: The code works for the example above but in my dataset I have 6 models and I get an error message, `Error: The RStudio 'Plots' window is too small to show this set of plots.
Please make the window larger.` I will figure this out, thanks.

Comment: see bottom of edited answer plz

Comment: one last request, how do i include a title on top of row , to show the model pertaining to the plot. I tried adding `labs(title = names(the_models ))` that did not work.